# SELECT switch/replace answer of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm a programmer with limited experience in SQL. But in essence what I want to do is something like

```
SELECT * FROM yesnomaybe_table;
```

My output:

```
yesnomaybe 
----------
0
1
2
1
```

My desired output:

```
yesnomaybe 
----------
45
64
55
64
```

I've looked into CASE like

```
SELECT yesnomaybe, 
    CASE WHEN yesnomaybe = 0 THEN 45
         WHEN yesnomaybe = 1 THEN 64
         ELSE 55
    END
FROM yesnomaybe_table;
```

But my output is this instead:

```
 yesnomaybe | case 
 -----------+------
     0      |   45
     1      |   64
     2      |   55
     1      |   64
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Remove the `yesnomaybe` column from the `select`?

Comment: By the way what is the problem with 0, 1, 2? It doesn't make too much sense to me to replace one set of numerical values with another set of numerical values, which looks more like random numbers for the first view to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN yesnomaybe = 0 THEN 45
         WHEN yesnomaybe = 1 THEN 64
         ELSE 55
    END as yesnomaybe
FROM yesnomaybe_table;
```

In your example you're selecting yesnomaybe, and then doing a switch without a name.